# Unrecognizable languages must be undecidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, decidability, turing-recognizable

A decidable language must be recognizable.

Unrecognizable languages must be undecidable?

I want to know more about the relation of undecidability and unrecognizability

Answer (score 1):

One of the most applicable basic laws of basic logic is the law of contraposition: $(P \rightarrow Q) \leftrightarrow (\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P)$.

Therefore, if you know decidable languages must be recognizable, its contrapositive readily follows: languages that are not recognizable can not be decidable.

For a more direct reasoning, observe that a decider for a language is always also a valid recognizer for a language. Therefore if a language has a decider, it also has a recognizer and therefore is recognizable; and if it has no recognizer, it cannot have a decider either.